# function (OccurencesOfPrimes < list >) which counts the number of primes in a (possibly nested) list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am working on problem to get the `occurence` of Prime in a list in lisp.
Input:
Write a function (`OccurencesOfPrimes < list >`) which counts the number of primes in a (possibly nested) list.

Output: Example: `(OccurencesOfPrimes (((1)(2))(5)(3)((8)3)) returns 4`.

I am using the below code but getting the error like:

```
(

defun OccurencesOfPrimes (list)
        (loop for i from 2 to 100 
            do ( setq isPrime t)
            (loop for j from 2 to i
                never (zerop (mod i j))
                    (setq isPrime f)
                    (break)
            )
        )
        (if (setq isPrime t)
            (append list i)
        )
        )
    )

LOOP: illegal syntax near (SETQ ISPRIME F) in
(LOOP FOR J FROM 2 TO I NEVER (ZEROP (MOD I J)) (SETQ ISPRIME F) (BREAK)
```

)

Any help.

Comment: isPrine is an undefined variable. The LOOP lacks a DO. BREAK calls the debugger...

Comment: You need to study the syntax of the language and do simpler exercises first; try to respect the conventions of the language, especially formatting and indentation. LOOP has a special syntax too. You might already have read those pages, but in case you didn't: http://www.cliki.net/Getting%20Started (many references) and http://www.cliki.net/Online%20tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to keep the format consistent with the expected conventions of the language. It helps when reading the code (in particular with other programmers), and can help you see errors.

Also, you should use an editor which, at the minimum, keep tracks of parentheses. In Emacs, when you put the cursor in the first opening parenthesis, the matching parenthesis is highlighted. You can spot that you have one additional parenthesis that serves no purpose.

```
(

defun OccurencesOfPrimes (list)
        (loop for i from 2 to 100 
            do ( setq isPrime t)
            (loop for j from 2 to i
                never (zerop (mod i j))
                    (setq isPrime f)
                    (break)
            )
        )
        (if (setq isPrime t)
            (append list i)
        )
        ) ;; <- end of defun
    ) ;; <- closes nothing
```

In Lisp, parentheses are for the computer, whereas indentation is for humans. Tools can automatically indent the code according to the structure (the parenthesis), and any discrepancy between what indentation you expect and the one being computed is a hint that your code is badly formed. If you look at the indentation of your expressions, you can see how deep you are in the form, and that alone helps you understand the code.

Symbol names are `dash-separated`, not `camlCased`.

Your code, with remarks:

```
(defun occurences-of-primes (list)
  ;; You argument is likely to be a LIST, given its name and the way
  ;; you call APPEND below. But you never iterate over the list. This
  ;; is suspicious.
  (loop
     for i from 2 to 100 
     do
       (setq is-prime t) ;; setting an undeclared variable
       (loop
          for j from 2 to i
          never (zerop (mod i j))

            ;; the following two forms are not expected here according
            ;; to LOOP's grammar; setting IS-PRIME to F, but F is not
            ;; an existing variable. If you want to set to false, use
            ;; NIL instead.
            (setq is-prime f)

            ;; BREAK enters the debugger, maybe you wanted to use
            ;; LOOP-FINISH instead, but the NEVER clause above should
            ;; already be enough to exit the loop as soon as its
            ;; sub-expression evaluates to NIL.
            (break)))

  ;; The return value of (SETQ X V) is V, so here your test would
  ;; always succeed.
  (if (setq is-prime t)
      ;; Append RETURNS a new list, without modifying its
      ;; arguments. In particular, LIST is not modified. Note that "I"
      ;; is unknown at this point, because the bindings effective
      ;; inside the LOOP are not visible in this scope. Besides, "I"
      ;; is a number, not a list.
      (append list i)))
```

### Original question

> Write one function which counts all the occurrences of a prime number in a (possibly nested) list.

Even though the homework questions says "write one function", it does not say that you should write one big function that compute everything at once. You *could* write one such big function, but if you split your problem into sub-problems, you will end with different auxiliary functions, which:

1. are simpler to understand (they do one thing)
2. can be reused to build other functions

The sub-problems are, for example: how to determine if a number is a prime? how to iterate over a tree (a.k.a. a possibly nested list)? how to count
the occurrences?

The basic idea is to write an "is-prime" function, iterate over the tree and call "is-prime" on each element; if the element is prime and was never seen before, add 1 to a counter, local to your function.

You can also flatten the input tree, to obtain a list, then sort the resulting
list; you iterate over the list while keeping track of the last
value seen: if the value is the same as the previous one, you
already know if the number is prime; if the previous number differs, then
you have to test if the number is prime first.

You could also abstract things a little more, and define a higher-order tree-walker function, which calls a function on each leaf of the tree. And write another higher-order function which "memoizes" calls: it wraps around a
 function F so that if you call F with the same arguments as before,
 it returns the result that was stored instead of recomputing it.

### Example

I'll combine the above ideas because if you give that answer to a teacher you are likely to have to carefully explain what each part does (and if you can, great for you); this is not necessarily the "best" answer, but it covers a lot of things.

```
(defun tree-walk-leaves (tree function)
  (typecase tree
    (null nil)
    (cons
      (tree-walk-leaves (car tree) function)
      (tree-walk-leaves (cdr tree) function))
    (t (funcall function tree))))

(defun flatten (tree &optional keep-order-p)
  (let ((flat nil))
    (tree-walk-leaves tree (lambda (leaf) (push leaf flat)))
    (if keep-order-p
        (nreverse flat)
        flat)))

(defun prime-p (n)
  (or (= n 2)
      (and (> n 2)
           (oddp n)
           (loop
              for d from 3 upto (isqrt n) by 2
              never (zerop (mod n d))))))

(defun count-occurences-of-prime (tree)
  (count-if #'prime-p (remove-duplicates (flatten tree))))

(count-occurences-of-prime '(((1)(2))(5)(3)((8)3)))
=> 4
```

If, instead, you don't want to remove duplicates but count the multiple times a prime number occurs, you can do:

```
(count-if (memoize #'prime-p) (flatten tree))
```

... where `memoize` is:

```
(defun memoize (function &key (test #'equalp) (key #'identity))
  (let ((hash (make-hash-table :test test)))
    (lambda (&rest args)
      (let ((args (funcall key args)))
        (multiple-value-bind (result exists-p) (gethash args hash)
          (values-list
           (if exists-p
               result
               (setf (gethash args hash)
                     (multiple-value-list (apply function args))))))))))
```

*(memoize is useless if there are no duplicates)*